# Work with Old Typescript Widgets library in Jhipster

Tags: javascript, typescript, jhipster, gantt-chart, dhtmlx

I am trying to get old version of external Typescript/javascript widget library in Jhipster version 6.10+ & 7.0 beta.[This issue will also hit non Jhipster apps in Latest Angular and React Apps] Example Libraries include DHTMLX, bryntum Gantt etc. Unfortunately both libraries only support Angular 2 (old version of typescript standard). Trying to integrate these widget results into lot of typescript errors in these library and hence i have hit a roadblock. Few workaround/hacks that I am thinking

1. Make Use of standard HTML/javascript way and embed the html as iframe inside Jhipster app.
2. Use themeleaf to render standard HTML/javascript or JSP page that embed these Widgets

Does anyone has a better alternative? Also suggest what changes that I will need to make in webpack to implement one of the above workaround

Comment: Bryntum supports any version of Angular / Typescript. Demos: https://bryntum.com/examples/gantt/#Integration/Angular

Answer (score 0):

DHTMLX Gantt should work in Angular 9 and 10. Here are the demos:

[Angular 10](https://files.dhtmlx.com/30d/5c27a7e5dfbb10ff8473fbdf15fca6b0/angular10+gantt_7.0.5_trial.zip)

[Angular 9](https://files.dhtmlx.com/30d/f71045d1f3b551868dbf709440c3feba/angular9+different_instances_7.0.5_trial.zip)

Comment: Seeing Following Error, any patch fix in DHTMLX?


Error:
C:\Work\Projects\App\App\gantt_7.0.5_evaluation\codebase\dhtmlxgantt.js
  10:439829  error  Parsing error: Identifier expected. 'null' is a reserved word that cannot be used here

Comment: Do you have Angular 11 Demo? Support for Latest Typescript version? Since both of these demos are not working in Angular 11/Typescript 4.0+

Comment: Here are the demos for Angular 11. The Trial version has the Gantt instance approach(create and destroy the Gantt instances) and uses the Gantt types, while the GPL version allows all types for Gantt:


https://files.dhtmlx.com/30d/cfa203d2fbcb7066a780a2eb2569f683/angular11+gantt_7.0.5-trial.zip

https://files.dhtmlx.com/30d/9a846d6e49c55de8f7fef16e13014db9/angular11+gantt_7.0_GPL.zip